# I need to remove duplicate images from my wordpress media library

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to remove duplicate images from my wordpress media library.

The posts themselves aren't duplicate but each attachment image is appearing twice for each post.

I've had a look around but nobody quite has a clear cut answer. Some people have said use something like this:

```
  <?php 
    $p = get_posts(array('numberposts'=> -1));
    foreach($p as $t) {
      $s = get_children(array('post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1 )); 
      foreach ($s as $u) {
        var_dump($u);
      }
    }
  ?>
```

But there still seems to be a bit missing, like this brings me a list of attachments but I still don't know how to compare them.

It seems to me that I need to use some sql queries and delete the media files straight from the database. I'm not quite sure how to go about this though.

Theoretically I need to attempt something like find posts, foreach post get attachments, if attachment filename == filename then delete filename.

Help appreciated.

Comment: The files won't be in the database. They're saved in your /uploads/ folder. How many files do you have?

Comment: @henrywright well now it's more like 3000

Answer (score 1):

Create a file in your theme folder and in that paste either the first or second way solutions:

**1st way (Compare against their titles - recommended):**

```
<?php

require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');
global $wpdb;

$querys = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT a.ID, a.post_title, a.post_type
    FROM $wpdb->posts AS a
       INNER JOIN (
          SELECT post_title, MIN( id ) AS min_id
          FROM $wpdb->posts
          WHERE post_type = 'attachment'
          GROUP BY post_title
          HAVING COUNT( * ) > 1
       ) AS b ON b.post_title = a.post_title
    AND b.min_id <> a.id
    AND a.post_type = 'attachment'
    ");

echo "<style>td {padding:0 0 10px;}</style>";
echo "<h2>DUPLICATES</h2>\n";
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr><th></th><th>Title</th><th>URL</th></tr>\n";

foreach ( $querys as $query )
{
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($query->ID);
    $delete_url = get_delete_post_link($query->ID);
    $delete_url = get_delete_post_link($query->ID);
    echo "<tr>
        <td><a style=\"color: #FFF;background-color: #E74C3C;text-decoration: none;padding: 5px;\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"".$delete_url."\">DELETE</a></td>
        <td>".get_the_title($query->ID)."</td>
        <td><a href=\"".$attachment_url."\">".$attachment_url."</a></td>
        </tr>\n";
}

echo "</table>";

?>
```

**2nd way (Compare against their urls)**
The way it works is, it checks each file against each other. So if you have a file like file.jpg and file1.jpg, then it will catch them as duplicates. Also, if you have a file like file1.jpg and file11.jpg, then it will catch them as duplicates even though they might be completely different files.
:

```
<?php

require('../../../wp-blog-header.php');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'name',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => null, // any parent
);

$newArray = array();

$attachments = get_posts($args);
$attachments2 = $attachments;


if ($attachments){

    foreach($attachments as $post){
        $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url($post->ID);
        $delete_url = get_delete_post_link($post->ID);
        $newArray[] = array("att_url" => $attachment_url, "del_url" => $delete_url);
    }

    echo "<table>";
        $newArray2 = $newArray;
        echo "<tr><td><h2>DUPLICATES</h2></td></tr>";
        foreach($newArray as $url1){
            $url_del = $url1['del_url'];
            $url1 = $url1['att_url'];
            $url11 = substr($url1,0,strrpos($url1,"."));
            foreach($newArray2 as $url2){
                $url2 = $url2['att_url'];
                $url2 = substr($url2,0,strrpos($url2,".") - 1);

                if($url2 == $url11)
                {
                    echo "<tr><td><a href=\"".$url_del."\">DELETE</a></td><td><a href=\"".$url1."\">".$url1."</a></td></tr>";
                }
            }
        }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr><td><h2>ALL ATTACHMENTS</h2></td></tr>";

        foreach($attachments as $tst1){
            echo "<tr><td>".$tst1->guid."</td></tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Then try to access that file in your browser and it will show you a list of all the duplicates.